# Detect null object in powershell:

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory

I am working on implementing some user creation in active directory using the built in powershell commandlets, recently I came across this issue.  When attempting to read in a data file of users where $_.UID is one of the fields in the file, I do a Get-ADUser with the UID to check if the user already exists in ldap. If I get a null object, then I would like to create the user because this id is not already in ldap otherwise I would like to skip the entry in the datafile.  My script as is creates the users the first time through. If I run it a second time on the same data file (users should no longer be null for the UID field) the if condition is still true and the script attempts to create users a second time.  I am new to powershell scripting so I must be misunderstanding something.  What am I doing wrong?  Your help is appreciated!

```
Function createUsers{
Import-CSV "~\Desktop\inData.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $USER  = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(uid=$_.UID)"

    if($USER -eq $Null){   #BROKEN DOESN'T DO ANYTHING
                           #(!$USER) Doesn't work either 
        Write-Host "Making next user."
        .
        .
        .

    }else{
        Write-Host "Skipping, user exists!!"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in your Get-ADUser Query. There is no property called "uid" in Active Directory. This will make $USER always null, and cause it to always want to create a new user.

Try using sAMAccountName instead:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$_.UID)"
```

To get a full list of all the properties available to you, I like to execute the following:

```
Get-ADUser MyUserName -Properties *
```